# compile syzkaller fuzzer failed without any error or warning

Tags: go, compilation, fuzzing

I encountered an issue while compiling syzkaller ([a customized version of syzkaller](https://github.com/seclab-fudan/SyzDirect/tree/main/source/syzdirect/syzdirect_fuzzer), based on syzkaller commit a371c43c33b6f901421f93b655442363c072d251,Compiling on this commit was successful).

When using make fuzzer, I received a message saying

```
build constraints exclude all Go files in xxx
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVtIO.png)
Since my environment is amd64 and Linux, I thought this would be normal; however, the compilation failed.

I tried to use -x and -v to display the compilation logs, but -v did not produce any output, and the file /tmp/go-xxxxx generated by -x was empty.

here is the compile command:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnZs7.png)

I would like to know why the compilation fails, as it does not display any errors or warnings. Is there any way to make Go show this information?

I tried to use -x and -v to display the compilation logs, but -v did not produce any output, and the file /tmp/go-xxxxx generated by -x was empty.

here is the full output :

```
zec@creat2012-Inspiron-3910:~/SyzDirect/source/syzdirect/syzdirect_fuzzer$ make fuzzer
go list -f '{{.Stale}}' ./sys/syz-sysgen | grep -q false || go install ./sys/syz-sysgen
make .descriptions
make[1]: '.descriptions' is up to date.
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build "-ldflags=-s -w -X github.com/google/syzkaller/prog.GitRevision=02c9a6504a757e6cec0f10202624d175aa474d94+ -X 'github.com/google/syzkaller/prog.gitRevisionDate=20240118-134457'" "-tags=syz_target syz_os_linux syz_arch_amd64 " -o ./bin/linux_amd64/syz-fuzzer github.com/google/syzkaller/syz-fuzzer
package github.com/google/syzkaller/syz-fuzzer
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover/backend
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/host
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/csource
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/mgrconfig
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys/akaros/gen: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/zec/SyzDirect/source/syzdirect/syzdirect_fuzzer/sys/akaros/gen
package github.com/google/syzkaller/syz-fuzzer
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover/backend
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/host
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/csource
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/mgrconfig
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys/darwin/gen: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/zec/SyzDirect/source/syzdirect/syzdirect_fuzzer/sys/darwin/gen
package github.com/google/syzkaller/syz-fuzzer
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover/backend
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/host
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/csource
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/mgrconfig
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys/freebsd/gen: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/zec/SyzDirect/source/syzdirect/syzdirect_fuzzer/sys/freebsd/gen
package github.com/google/syzkaller/syz-fuzzer
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover/backend
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/host
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/csource
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/mgrconfig
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys/fuchsia/gen: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/zec/SyzDirect/source/syzdirect/syzdirect_fuzzer/sys/fuchsia/gen
package github.com/google/syzkaller/syz-fuzzer
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover/backend
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/host
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/csource
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/mgrconfig
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys/netbsd/gen: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/zec/SyzDirect/source/syzdirect/syzdirect_fuzzer/sys/netbsd/gen
package github.com/google/syzkaller/syz-fuzzer
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover/backend
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/host
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/csource
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/mgrconfig
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys/openbsd/gen: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/zec/SyzDirect/source/syzdirect/syzdirect_fuzzer/sys/openbsd/gen
package github.com/google/syzkaller/syz-fuzzer
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover/backend
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/host
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/csource
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/mgrconfig
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys/test/gen: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/zec/SyzDirect/source/syzdirect/syzdirect_fuzzer/sys/test/gen
package github.com/google/syzkaller/syz-fuzzer
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover/backend
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/host
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/csource
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/mgrconfig
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys/trusty/gen: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/zec/SyzDirect/source/syzdirect/syzdirect_fuzzer/sys/trusty/gen
package github.com/google/syzkaller/syz-fuzzer
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/cover/backend
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/host
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/csource
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/pkg/mgrconfig
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys
        imports github.com/google/syzkaller/sys/windows/gen: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/zec/SyzDirect/source/syzdirect/syzdirect_fuzzer/sys/windows/gen
make: *** [Makefile:158: fuzzer] Error 1
```

Comment: What if you try to build the original https://github.com/google/syzkaller? Does it not fail?

Comment: original syzkaller build successful, but the customized syzkaller build failed, and it seems no compile error or warning during compiling customized syzkaller